# Simple CURL copy not working?

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL to copy files:

```
$ch = curl_init ($copyMe);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9");
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen($toTarget,'x');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
```

The problem is, the moment the file is big (over 3Mb), the server ends up with a file of size 0Kb. So my questions is.... why does CURL not copy large files and what am I missing to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to remove the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT?

Comment: and also if you have `allow_url_fopen` set to On you could try doing the same thing with file_get_contents/file_put_contents just as a test to see if it's because of the way files are written or because of the remote server

Comment: There's `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to debug the session

Comment: Timeout removal didnt work. That was the first thing i tried.

Comment: You ran out of disc space ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send output directly to file:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```